# Bands disappear after Raster Calculation ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, image, multi-band

I have a tif file containing 36 bands. After I applied raster calculation on the file the bands aggregate into one single band which I don't want because I need them for further calculation. People say that I can apply raster calculation on each band. I can do that but it is too troublesome .Is there any better way to keep all the bands as well as performing calculations on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a multi-band raster input, the Raster Calculator will only process the [first band](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005900000005000000#ESRI_SECTION1_DE8B152D7A034536AF79348FFE7B7D8A):

> **Multiband raster data**
>
> When a multiband raster is used as input, most Spatial Analyst tools operate only on the first band.
>
> The exceptions are certain tools in the Multivariate and Extraction toolsets which do process each of the bands in a multiband input and can create a multiband output.

Two options are to process the bands individually (you [don't need to extract](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150067/access-individual-bands-and-use-them-in-map-algebra) them out to new files) and [composite](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/composite-bands-function.htm) the results. Or to use numpy in python.