# Accessing individual raster bands using arcpy Raster class?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am working with rasters in arcpy and I am not able to access individual bands using the Raster class. The same code that worked about a year ago no longer works.

I should be able to access a single band of a raster like so:

`Band3 = Raster(raster_filename + "/Band_3")`

But the resulting Band3 variable has all 6 bands in the raster, not just band 3.

The `"/Band_3"` syntax appears to work fine in the Describe method in the first half of the following code but doesn't work in the Raster class later on:

```
    folder = r"C:\Users\elyons\Desktop\Spring_2018\Labs\New_LabData"

    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    raster_filename = "Landsat.tif"

    #Create describe objects
    desc = arcpy.Describe(raster_filename)
    desc_band = arcpy.Describe(raster_filename + "/Band_3")

    #These are properties of the describe raster BAND object
    print "Height = " + str(desc_band.height)
    print "Width = " + str(desc_band.width)
    print "Resolution = " + str(desc_band.meanCellWidth)

    #This one is a property of the describe raster dataset object
    print "Number of Bands is = " + str(desc.bandCount)

    #Open bands as raster band objects
    Band3 = Raster(raster_filename + "/Band_3")

    #print number of bands
    print Band3.bandCount

    #Save the raster
    print "saving"
    Band3.save("savebandtest.tif")
    print "saved"


    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
```

The above code prints out the correct information for the describe objects and then prints `6` for `Band3.bandCount`, which is not right. It then saves a six band raster to the filename `savebandtest.tif` that is identical to `Landsat.tif`. I have tried different multiband rasters, different computers, getting the band name programatically, setting the working directory to the raster, forward slashes, backward slashes, everything I can think of.

Has the syntax changed for accessing single bands from multiband raster files? I can't find any mention of a change in the help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether your band names are actually "Band_1" to "Band_N" or something else like 'CoastalAerosol', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red', etc...

If you want to access the bands by index, use the [Make Raster Layer (Data Management)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-raster-layer.htm) tool.

See also [Access individual bands and use them in map algebra](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/150067/2856).

Comment: The band names in this case are the default "Band_1" etc. I used the method from the linked thread but am still having the same problem and it should be insensitive to the band names.

Answer (score 1):

You can acess the individual bandnames using the Describe's children property.

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
for rband in desc.children:
    print rband.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found that you actually need a backslash, in the python console the syntax looks something like:

```
out_raster = arcpy.ia.FocalStatistics(r"C:\Users\BigBoy\BigBoyTif.tif\Band_1",...
```

Meanwhile in geoprocessing it should be that the Input raster is

C:\Users\BigBoy\BigBoyTif.tif\Band_1