# Access layer of raster stored in memory using ArcPy to create NDVI from subset of multi-band raster

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, ndvi, error-000732

I am trying to create a final output of an NDVI raster for a number of Landsat images run through a for loop in Python 3 (for ArcGIS Pro). I am able to produce the NDVI rasters when I save the intermediary Landsat subset from ExtractByMask, but receive the following error when I instead try to store the intermediary subset in memory:

```
nir_raster = arcpy.Raster(nir)
```

> RuntimeError:  ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset in_memory\myMemoryRaster\Layer_4 does not exist or is not supported

Here is the code where I attempt to refer to layers of the raster in memory (in my case layers 4 and 3 refer to NIR and red bands, respectively in my particular multi-band raster).

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'

# Define area of interest for subset
aoi = 'P:/aoi/aoi.shp'
aoi_name = os.path.basename(aoi)

# Select Landsat Images 
images= "P:/Landsat/L7_p39r37_01242016_b2-5_7.img; P:/Landsat/L8_p39r37_02172016_b2-7.img"
image_list = images.split(";") # used here because real script takes multi-value parameter for images

# Select output folder to which NDVI rasters will be saved to
output_workspace = 'P:/NDVI'

# 1. Generate NDVI raster
for i in image_list:

    image_name = os.path.basename(i) 
    image_name_chunks = image_name.split('_')
    ndvi_name = 'ndvi_' + image_name_chunks[2] +'.img'
    ndvi = os.path.join(output_workspace, ndvi_name)

    # 1.1 Subset image
    outExtractByMask = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(in_raster = i, in_mask_data = aoi)
    output = "in_memory" + "\\" + "myMemoryRaster"
    outExtractByMask.save(output)

    # 1.2 Calculate NDVI on subset
    nir = output + '\Layer_4'
    nir_raster = arcpy.Raster(nir)

    red = output + '\Layer_3'
    red_raster = arcpy.Raster(red)

    numerator = arcpy.sa.Float(nir_raster - red_raster)
    denominator = arcpy.sa.Float(nir_raster + red_raster)

    ndvi_output = arcpy.sa.Divide(numerator, denominator)
    ndvi_output.save(ndvi)

arcpy.Delete_management('in_memory')
```

However, when I substitute the following code in sections 1.1 and 1.2 (i.e. not saving subset to memory) my code runs fine:

```
# 1.1 Subset image
subset_name = image_name[:-4] + '_' + aoi_name[:-8] + '_subset.img'

subset = os.path.join(output_workspace, subset_name)

subset_output = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(in_raster = i, in_mask_data = aoi)
subset_output.save(subset) 

# 1.2 Calculate NDVI on subset

nir = subset + '\Layer_4'
nir_raster = arcpy.Raster(nir)
red = subset + '\Layer_3'
red_raster = arcpy.Raster(red)
```

I've visited: [Access individual bands and use them in map algebra](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150067/access-individual-bands-and-use-them-in-map-algebra)
and
[What is the proper syntax and usage for ArcGIS "in_memory" workspace?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35468/what-is-the-proper-syntax-and-usage-for-arcgis-in-memory-workspace)

Update: adding multi-line version of user2856's Describe note below:

```
for child in arcpy.da.Describe(outExtractByMask)['children']:
    print(child['catalogPath'])
```

Comment: Could you please show what the following output looks like: `print(nir)`?

Comment: @Aaron For sure. It reads: in_memory\myMemoryRaster\Layer_4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the band name wrong, check them using `arcpy.da.Describe`, i.e.

```
print([child['catalogPath'] for child in arcpy.da.Describe(outExtractByMask)['children']])
```

I get the band names as `'Band_1'` to `'Band_<N>'`.

You could create a little function* to automatically pull out the band names, then your code would look something like:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'

def get_bands(raster):
    bands = [arcpy.Raster(band['catalogPath'] for band in arcpy.da.Describe(raster)['children']]
    return bands

# Define area of interest for subset
etc......

# 1. Generate NDVI raster
for i in image_list:
    etc...

    # 1.2 Calculate NDVI on subset
    bands = get_bands(outExtractByMask)
    nir_raster = bands[3]  # list begins at 0, so bands[3] = Band 4
    red_raster = bands[2]
```

---

* Note for any ArcGIS Desktop users who may try to use this function, `arcpy.da.Describe` is *only* [available in ArcGIS Pro](https://community.esri.com/ideas/13679-implement-arcpydadescribe-in-arcmap) `arcpy`.  This code will not work in ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap etc.).

Comment: Very interesting! print([child['catalogPath'] for child in arcpy.da.Describe(outExtractByMask)['children']])
reads: ['in_memory\\myMemoryRaster\\Band_1', 'in_memory\\myMemoryRaster\\Band_2', 'in_memory\\myMemoryRaster\\Band_3', 'in_memory\\myMemoryRaster\\Band_4', 'in_memory\\myMemoryRaster\\Band_5', 'in_memory\\myMemoryRaster\\Band_6']

Comment: Thank you! It ran perfectly once I simply changed Layer to Band in section 1.2 as in:                              
    nir = output + '\\Band_4'

Comment: Though it's confusing to me why the result of print(nir) still reads in_memory\myMemoryRaster\Layer_4? Band is nowhere there.

Comment: @Iracambi I believe you are explicitly defining Layer_4 in your script.

Comment: @Aaron, Ah, yes, of course! Thank you :)

Comment: However, it's still confusing to me that \Layer_4 is recognized on my raster subset saved to disk, but then only \Band_4 is recognized on the subset raster saved in_memory.