# Getting band names using ArcPy in ArcGIS Desktop 10.x

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, band, arcgis-10.7

How do I get a list of band names using ArcPy in ArcGIS Desktop 10.x?

In ArcGIS Pro, I can use `Raster('myRaster').bandNames`, but this is not an option in ArcGIS 10.x and I cannot seem to figure out how to access band names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access individual bands and use them in map algebra](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150067/access-individual-bands-and-use-them-in-map-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the band names you can set `arcpy.env.workspace` to the raster, then use `arcpy.ListRasters()` to list the bands, here's an example wrapped up into a function:

```
import arcpy

def get_bands(path_to_raster):
    """ Get a list of band names from a multiband raster """

    # Save previous workspace
    oldws = arcpy.env.workspace 

    #Get raster objects from band names
    arcpy.env.workspace = path_to_raster
    bands = arcpy.ListRasters()

    #Restore previous workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = oldws

    return bands
```

Or if you want the full path:

```
import os
import arcpy

def get_bands(path_to_raster):
    """ Get a list of band names from a multiband raster """

    # Save previous workspace
    oldws = arcpy.env.workspace 

    #Get raster objects from band names
    arcpy.env.workspace = path_to_raster
    bands = [os.path.join(path_to_raster, b) for b in arcpy.ListRasters()]

    #Restore previous workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = oldws

    return bands
```

If you don't actually care what the band names are and want to access a raster band by index (band number), use `arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management`

```
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(input_raster, "lyr_band3", band_index="3")
```